# Why is Solve returning an empty list?

Tags: equation-solving

I evaluate

```
Solve[{-((2 (4 θ0 + θ1))/σ^2) - (2 (4 θ0 + θ2))/σ^2, 
       -((4 θ0 + θ1)/(2 σ^2)), -((4 θ0 + θ2)/(2 σ^2)),
       -(2/σ) + (4 θ0 + θ1)^2/(2 σ^3) 
       + (4 θ0 + θ2)^2/(2 σ^3)} == {0, 0, 0, 0} && σ > 0, 
      { θ0, θ1, θ2, σ}]
```

and `Solve` returns `{}`.  Why? Should it be able to solve the equation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Solve` works correctly, when returning `{}` it means there are no solutions.

To demonstrate it let's rewrite your system:

```
system = Thread[{-((2 (4 θ0 + θ1))/σ^2) - (2 (4 θ0 + θ2))/σ^2,
                 -((4 θ0 + θ1)/(2 σ^2)), 
                 -((4 θ0 + θ2)/(2 σ^2)), 
                 -(2/σ) + (4 θ0 + θ1)^2/(2 σ^3) + (4 θ0 + θ2)^2/(2 σ^3)} ==
                  {0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

> ```
> {-2 (4 θ0 + θ1)/σ^2 - 2 (4 θ0 + θ2)/σ^2 == 0,
>  -(4 θ0 + θ1)/(2 σ^2) == 0, 
>  -(4 θ0 + θ2)/(2 σ^2) == 0, 
>  -(2/σ) + (4 θ0 + θ1)^2/(2σ^3) + (4 θ0 + θ2)^2/(2 σ^3) == 0}
> ```

One can see from the second and third equations that we can define appropriate rules to simplify the system:

```
rules = { θ1 -> -4 θ0, θ2 -> -4 θ0};
```

Now we have:

```
system /. rules
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, -2/σ == 0}
> ```

Thus the system cannot be satisfied because `σ > 0` in your assumptions supplementing the `system`.

Comment: so when I get {}, it usually means that there is no solution?
So I've added '&& sigma > 0 && -4 <= teta1 <= 4 && -4 <= teta2 <= 4 && 0 < teta0 < 1' to the solve command. 
 And what does it mean this: «Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and
numericizing the result.» Is the solution still valid

Comment: In general `{}` means that there are no solutions. That warning can be returned if you put some machine precission numbers to inequalities so you shouldn't get it unless you put e.g. `4.` instead of `4`, however after the warning one gets `{}` what it should be. `Solve` can work with exact numbers, for machine precission ones use `NSolve`.

Comment: Also, although it is not the case here I want to add that `Solve` returns `{}` if there are no **general** solutions. So for instance `Solve[{a==1,b+1==c},c]` will return `{}`, even though there is a solution if you consider `a` to be a free parameter that can be fixed to 1 in the solution. Unless you add the option `MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic` or `MaxExtraConditions -> All`. (Or add it to the variables to be solved for by hand, but this can be inconvenient if you are actually working with a very large number of equations and parameters.)