# Problems with Solve returning {} solution. Can i get an analytical solution to this problem?

Tags: equation-solving

I have this system of three  equations and three unknowns:

```
eq1 = sigrrR == ((2 C2 + (C4 minusnu r^minusnu + C3 plusnu r^plusnu)/
      r^2) (1 - 2 G alpha - 
      2 E^(t gamma) G t alpha ExpIntegralEi[-t gamma]))/(2 G t);
eq2 = sigttR == ((2 C2 + (
      C4 (-1 + minusnu) minusnu r^minusnu + 
       C3 (-1 + plusnu) plusnu r^plusnu)/r^2) (1 - 2 G alpha - 
      2 E^(t gamma) G t alpha ExpIntegralEi[-t gamma]))/(2 G t);
eq3 = sigzzR == -(1/(
     24 G^3 K r^2 t z)) (2 G - 
      3 K) (3 K n r^2 (h (rhors - g rhowater) (3000 + z) - 
         z (-2 p + rhors (3000 + z))) + 
      G (-2 h n r^2 (rhors - g rhowater) (3000 + z) + 
         2 z (12 C2 K r^2 + 
            3 K (C4 minusnu^2 r^minusnu + C3 plusnu^2 r^plusnu) + 
            n r^2 (-2 p + rhors (3000 + z))))) (-1 + 2 G alpha + 
      2 E^(t gamma) G t alpha ExpIntegralEi[-t gamma]);
system = {eq1, eq2, eq3};
Solve[system, {C2, C3, C4}]
```

does anyone knows why the solution is {}?

Comment: Here is a basic issue regarding the underlying problem: [Why is Solve returning an empty list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43121/why-is-solve-returning-an-empty-list)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `Eliminate` can turn a complicated system into a simpler system with fewer variables. Suppose we try to find the single equation that results from eliminating `C2` and `C3` from your system. The plan is to then see if we can `Solve` for that final variable in the result.

```
FullSimplify[Eliminate[system, {C2, C3}]]
```

The result is almost immediate and is surprisingly compact, that is very unusual, usually if you eliminate n-1 out of n variables the resulting equation with the remaining variable is too big to be useful.

But, more interesting, there is no `C4` in the resulting equation. Likewise if you `Eliminate` `C2` and `C4` or if you `Eliminate` `C3` and `C4`. And all three of those results are equal.

Now you might ask yourself, what does this mean about your system? And what does that result from `Eliminate` say about your original problem?