# Problem with "Solve" in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following Equations

```
a11 = D[R T Exp[-a/(R T V)]/(V - b), T];
a21 = D[R T Exp[-a/(R T V)]/(V - b), {T, 2}];
```

When I use `Solve`, mathematica is unable to solve the equation

```
Solve[{a21 == 0, a11 == 0}, {T, V}]
```

Could you please tell me where the problem is?

Thank you so much

Comment: Take `Simplify[a21 == 0]` and this should enlighten you why there are no `T` and `V` satisfying `a21 == 0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Solve returning an empty list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43121/why-is-solve-returning-an-empty-list)

Answer (score 2):

MMA tells you that no solution exists. To see this solve the first equation for V:

```
s1 = Solve[{a11 == 0}, {V}][[1]]

{V -> -(a/(R T))}
```

Use this in the second equation:

```
a21 == 0 /. s1 //Simplify
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

You see that for no value of T the left hand side becomes zero, provided the numerator is different from zero.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `Reals` options.  Then `Solve`command shows there is no real solution.

```
a11 = D[R T Exp[-a/(R T V)]/(V - b), T];a21 = D[R T Exp[-a/(R T V)]/(V - b), {T, 2}];
Solve[{a21 == 0, a11 == 0}, {T, V}, Reals]
```

> `{}`

Comment: The same result `{}` is produced without the `Reals` option.